# Load an Image in Multiple movie clips using as3

Tags: arrays, image, actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

I am really curious of asking a particular question to everyone of you. I am creating an Application in flash that is lot similar to this Application [Zazzle Case Cover](http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-casemate_case?formfactor=apple_iphone5&style=barelythere)

I am almost ready with what i was supposed to do and How i have to do. But, still i am ain't a very big Tech_geek to handle all these . I list out some of the things which i could`nt achieve. Kindly help me if possible.

1. I know that inorder to load unlimited number of images in a Movie Clip, we need Array. But to go with it, I am not sure of framing it properly.
2. I have Merged certain codings from internet and encoded it to act as the Application in that Site for a Single image in a Single view, but when i try to add child or make it display the same image in all other views i can't frame the coding. It is not behaving properly .
3. Last but not the Least, I am confused of displaying the Bitmap data in as3... I wanted to show the Uploaded Panel Image in the below thmbnail area but i am not so sure of it.

The Questionnaire format of the Above problems are

- How to upload unlimited number of images in a Movie Clip using Array ?
- Is it is possible to Display the same image in two Movie Clips simultaneously using addChild ?
  I had lots of blah and blah but this area plays the 2nd Question and even Answer for it. But i am ain't sure revealing the Answer.

  ```
  function onMovieClipLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
  {
    // Hide progress bar
    progressBar.visible=false;
    var loadedContent:DisplayObject=event.target.content;
    var loader:Loader=event.target.loader as Loader;
    loadedContent.x=-37.625;
    loadedContent.y=-37.625;
    loadedContent.width=75.25;
    loadedContent.height=75.25;
    trace("loadedContent.width="+loadedContent.x);
    trace("loadedContent.height="+loadedContent.y);
    mcOnStage=true;  
    con1.container.addChild(loader);
    clears.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeMC);      
    function removeMC(MouseEvent):void {
      trace("Its Removed");
      if (mcOnStage ) 
      { 
        con1.container.removeChild(loader);
        con1.textcontainer.removeChild(txt);
        mcOnStage=false;
      } 
    }
  }
  ```

  "con1.container.addChild(loader);"

  Can i add "con1.container2.addChild(loader);" for the same loaded image.
- How to Clone a Movieclip's Bitmap data and Display it in another area or Movieclip ???

Guide me if possible...

I have included the SWF file along with this Question...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5jnHM1zpP4MOHRCeWFqX05sSTA/edit?usp=sharing

Can Someone check the first Site and gimme little notes of how can i bring all those modules in this flash as3 based application.

Comment: Can you share some source code, and also be more specific about your problems. Perhaps you should consider posting a question for each of your 3 problems.

Comment: @Gerve I have added up the Questions Bro ?!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would display the same image twice, with reference to the code you included in your post:

```
//here's your code
var loadedContent:DisplayObject=event.target.content as DisplayObject;

//create bitmap data instance same size and as the loaded content   
var transparent:Boolean = true; 
var fillColor:uint = 0xFFFFFFFF;    
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loadedContent.width, loadedContent.height, transparent, fillColor);

//draw the loaded content into the bitmap data
bitmapData.draw( loadedContent );

//create new bitmap 
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap( bitmapData);

//add the loaded content
con1.container.addChild(loader);

//add your 'cloned' content
con1.container2.addChild( bitmap );
```

Comment: But the Bitmap clone seems to be setting up in full image size view... Is there's a way i can scale it ??

Comment: var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix(); matrix.scale( .5); bitmapData.draw( loadedContent, matrix);

Comment: Have you seen my Output brother... Can you understand what am i asking ?

Comment: hello dude...  Can you understand what am i asking ? Have you seen my Output brother